# How to change the response content-type from text/html to image/png in react using fetch method

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm fetching random images from my react application, not from an external API but the content type of the response is in text/Html. how to change it to image/png.

here's my component below as I'm using fetch to make the call for my internal app.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "styles/modules/vehicle/map.scss";

const Map: React.FC<any> = () => {

  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' }
    fetch('/assets/tiles/18/153811/108130.png', { headers })
    .then(res => res)
    .then(data => setUrl(data.url))
  }, [])

  const getIcon = (iconSize) => {
    return L.icon({
      iconUrl: require("assets/images/png/location.png"),
      iconSize,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer 
        center={[30.02161, 31.25146]}
        zoom={18}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      >
        <TileLayer url={url} />
        <Marker position={[30.02161, 31.25146]} icon={getIcon(60)}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: Not sure if you can fetch an image like you're trying it. But you can get the image blob and render the bas64encoded image. Please have a look at the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-stallman-vk007q?file=/src/App.js). Is that working for you?

Comment: @AWolf Hi, it's not working, unfortunately, Should I upload these images into a server and make an API call for it?

Comment: Yes, you could create a server but if you're using create-react-app there is an easier way. Place your images into `public` folder and you can use fetch to load them - CRAs webpack configuration will handle the rest. I've added it to the sandbox. I would start with this. Later, you could check if you have a backend server for the api requests.

Comment: @AWolf thanks alot for your help, I created a backend server and uploaded the images and already things working great. Thanks alot